# mod_rewrite returns file name as opposed to value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm try to create a clean URL turning `http://www.example.com/view/index.php?id=12345` into `http://www.example.com/view/12345` by adding the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]*)$ view/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This returns the file name `index.php` as opposed to `12345` however. My error log is clear and I can't see what could be the issue here - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional match there

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /view/([^/\s?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ view/index.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Comment: 'GET' is now being returned, hmmm.

Comment: Please, refresh my answer by reloading the page.